# How do I cast from Integer to Fractional

Tags: haskell, types, casting

Let's say I have the following Haskell type description:

```
divide_by_hundred :: Integer -> IO()
divide_by_hundred n = print(n/100)
```

Why is it that when I attempt to run this through ghc I get:

```
No instance for (Fractional Integer) arising from a use of `/'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Fractional Integer)
In the first argument of `print', namely `(n / 100)'
In the expression: print (n / 100)
In an equation for `divide_by_hundred':
    divide_by_hundred n = print (n / 100)
```

By running `:t (/)`
I get:

```
(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
```

which, to me, suggests that the (/) can take any Num that can be expressed as fractional (which I was under the impression should include Integer, though I am unsure as how to verify this), as long as both inputs to `/` are of the same type.

This is clearly not accurate. Why? And how would I write a simple function to divide an Integer by 100?

Comment: Please make it a habit to write such tests as _pure functions_, not in the `IO` monad. Amongst other advantages, this makes the return type explicit (`print` hides the type), which gives more control. – Also, note that camelCase is convention amongst Haskellers. So, you should really have `divideByHundred :: Integer -> Integer`, or else `divideByHundred :: (Fractional f) => Integer -> f`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Haskell likes to keep to the mathematically accepted meaning of operators. `/` should be the inverse of multiplication, but e.g. `5 / 4 * 4` couldn't possibly yield `5` for a `Fractional Integer` instance<sup>1</sup>.

So if you actually mean to do truncated integer division, the language forces you<sup>2</sup> to make that explicit by using `div` or `quot`. OTOH, if you actually want the result as a fraction, you can use `/` fine, but you first need to convert to a type with a `Fractional` instance. For instance,

```
Prelude> let x = 5
Prelude> :t x
x :: Integer
Prelude> let y = fromIntegral x / 100
Prelude> y
5.0e-2
Prelude> :t y
y :: Double
```

Note that GHCi has selected the `Double` instance here because that's the simples default; you could also do

```
Prelude> let y' = fromIntegral x / 100 :: Rational
Prelude> y'
1 % 20
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Strictly speaking, this inverse identity doesn't quite hold for the `Double` instance either because of floating-point glitches, but there it's true at least approximately.

<sup>2</sup>Actually, not the language but the standard libraries. You could define

```
instance Fractional Integer where
  (/) = div
```

yourself, then your original code would work just fine. Only, it's a bad idea!

Answer (score 6):

You can use `div` for integer division:

```
div :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
```

Or you can convert your integers to fractionals using `fromIntegral`:

```
fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b
```

So in essence:

```
divide_by_hundred :: Integer -> IO()
divide_by_hundred n = print $ fromIntegral n / 100
```

---

Integers do not implement Fractional, which you can see in [the manual](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#t%3aInteger).

Comment: How to turn it back to a string after turning it into fractional using fromIntegral?